# Django SECRET_KEY protection VS allow anyone to run project locally

Tags: python, django, secret-key

I have read many topics here about django `SECRET_KEY`, but most of them are about how to store it in environment variable instead of `settings.py`, at this stage everything is clear. Currently i keep it in `.env` locally and in `config` var on heroku.

Im confused about 2 conflicting points that i can't combine together.

1. It considers as a good practice to keep `SECRET_KEY` in secret. From
   the docs:

   > Instead of hardcoding the secret key in your settings module, consider
   > loading it from an environment variable

   Besides that github warms in email if you have `SECRET_KEY` explicit
   in your code:

   > GitGuardian has detected the following Django Secret Key exposed
   > within your GitHub account.
2. I want to allow anyone to run my project locally. I have it on
   github and deployed version on heroku, but it's still a demo project
   which is used as part of portfolio, not a serious one.

So if i put `SECRET_KEY` in local environment, people who `git clone` my app and try to run it, obviously, won't be able to do that since they don't have access to `SECRET_KEY` in my environment.

What is the solution here? Should i break the protection convention and put it explicitly in `settings.py`?

Comment: *GitGuardian has detected the following Django Secret Key exposed within your GitHub account.* when you push your code you should add **.env** file inside your **.gitignore** file

Comment: Sure! I have it there. This sentence about GitGuardian purpose is to point out, that Git suppose you to hide SECRET_KEY if you try to commit settings.py with it.

Comment: If the project is supposed to be public, just ignore the warning mail. Also, point out to your users in the README to change the `SECRET_KEY` in production.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following snippet of code:

```
from warnings import warn
from uuid import uuid1

def parse_bool(value):
    if not value:
        return False
    if isinstance(value, str):
        if value.isdigit():
            value = int(value)
        else:
            value = value.lower() != 'false'
    return bool(value)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = parse_bool(os.getenv('DEBUG'))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
if os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'):
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
elif DEBUG:
    SECRET_KEY = 'secret'
else:
    SECRET_KEY = str(uuid1())
    warn('Using random SECRET_KEY. '
         'Should configure it for production.')
```

The trade-offs are

- Non-`DEBUG` by default meaning smaller chance to deploy in `DEBUG` mode.
- Reads `SECRET_KEY` from environment when available.
- In `DEBUG` uses hard-coded `SECRET_KEY` so that sessions are preserved when developing.
- Generates one-time `SECRET_KEY` when no `SECRET_KEY` is provided and not in `DEBUG`. This still allows to run the code without proper configuration and hard-coding a production key and should be safe enough since the keys are one-off.

To sum it up, with no configuration it runs production with fairly strong one-off key with the main disadvantage of being forced to re-login after each restart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are multiple solutions that differ on how easy to use they are vs how secure they are.

You could use a default value as fallback for the environment variable. Also you might want to ensure this only works if `DEBUG` is set to `True`, so nobody uses the default key in production.